# How to use DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction in ELKI

Tags: data-mining, elki

Does anyone know how I am supposed to use the `DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction` in ELKI?

When try to use it I get `Constraint: distance.latitudedim >= 0.`

but what is `-distance.latitudedim` exactly? Does it let me specify meters instead of degrees maybe?
But how do I do that? When I look in the code I can see it's an integer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELKI parameters have a documentation. You can find it in command line help (using `-help` or `-description <classname>`), or in the **tooltips** of the MiniGUI. I have to gree that the MiniGUI could make this easier accessible, but I'm not very good at UI design, and the UI is completely generic, generated programmatically from the available parameters.

The following is the output of command line ELKI,

```
java -jar elki.jar KDDCLIApplication -description
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction.geo.DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction
```

which yields the parameter explanation:

```
Description for class
de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction.geo.DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction
DimensionSelectingLatLngDistanceFunction
-distance.latitudedim <int>
    The dimension containing the latitude.
    Constraint: distance.latitudedim >= 0.
-distance.longitudedim <int>
    The dimension containing the longitude.
    Constraint: distance.longitudedim >= 0.
-geo.model <class|object>
    Earth model to use for projection. Default: spherical model.
    Implementing de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.math.geodesy.EarthModel
    Known classes (default package de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.math.geodesy):
    -> SphericalHaversineEarthModel
    -> SphericalVincentyEarthModel
    -> SphericalCosineEarthModel
    -> WGS84SpheroidEarthModel
    -> GRS80SpheroidEarthModel
    -> WGS72SpheroidEarthModel
    -> GRS67SpheroidEarthModel
    -> Clarke1880SpheroidEarthModel
    -> Clarke1858SpheroidEarthModel
    Default: SphericalVincentyEarthModel
```

The short explanation is: it's te **attribute numbers** (starting at 0, integer, and non-negative) containing the latitude and longitude within each vector. So if your CSV file has columns

```
shoe-size latitude random-number longitude weight
```

then you'd use `-distance.latitudedim 1 -distance.longitudedim 3`.